# Remove/Hide Table <tr>(s) which Their <td>(s) Does not Have Text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/u0b0djzy/3/) and let me know how I can hide or remove all rows in a dynamic table that their `<td>` (if all of them in a row) are empty? This is mainly happend at the end of the table since I generated a table with 5 rows but some times I am getting only 3 or 4 rows data from the data source.

Please be informed that by empty I mean a text value not a html element like div.

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="monBox">Jill</td>
        <td class="monBox">Smith</td>
        <td class="monBox">50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="monBox">Eve</td>
        <td class="monBox">Jackson</td>
        <td class="monBox">94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="monBox"></td>
        <td class="monBox"></td>
        <td class="monBox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="monBox">Eve</td>
        <td class="monBox">Jackson</td>
        <td class="monBox">94</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="monBox"></td>
        <td class="monBox"></td>
        <td class="monBox"></td>
    </tr>   

</table>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going through each tr and checking if all td elements inside are empty like so

```
$('table').find('tr').each (function() {

    var rows = 0;
    var rows_empty = 0;

     $(this).find('td').each (function() {
          rows++;
          if($(this).text().trim() == "")
              rows_empty++;
    }); 

    if(rows === rows_empty)
        $(this).remove();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oL5x6k7y/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, note I've given the table an ID of `target`:

```
//Loop through rows with empty cells
$("#target tr").has("td:empty").each(function(){
    //hide the row if all cells are empty
    if($(this).find("td").length === $(this).find("td:empty").length){
        $(this).hide();    
   }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0b0djzy/5/)

Or slightly simpler:

```
$("#target tr").has("td:empty").each(function(){
    if($(this).find("td:not(:empty)").length === 0){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Or Better Still:

`$('#target tr').not(':has(td:not(:empty))').remove();`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u0b0djzy/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#target tr').each(function(index,el).   
 { 
    if($.trim($(this).text()) == '')
    {
       $(this).remove();
    }
}
);
```

It works without checking table cells at all